# How to force the content text of a notification to be shown

Tags: android, notifications

I created a notification that contains a title, content text and a progressbar

The content text shows the percentage of a download.

The problem is that my notification sometimes has a long title and this will cause the content text to be hidden/invisible.

Is there a way of ellipsizing the title or forcing the content text to be shown?

my builder looks like this:

```
        builder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
        builder.setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download);
        builder.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getBaseContext(), R.color.colorPrimary));
        builder.setContentTitle(bookTitle);
        builder.setContentText(getString(R.string.downloadservice_status_busy));
        builder.setProgress(PROGRESS_MAX, 0, false);
        builder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
        builder.setOnlyAlertOnce(true);
        builder.setOngoing(true);
```

Comment: are you using custom layout for notification ?

Comment: no i do not, should i ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following ways:

**1.**`NotificationCompat.Builder` has several style mode.

- Big content title style:

```
builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle(builder)
                .bigText(bigText)
                .setBigContentTitle(bigContentTitleText)
                .setSummaryText(summaryText)
        )
```

- Big picture style:

```
 builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle(builder)
                .bigLargeIcon(your_bitmap_1)
                .bigPicture(your_bitmap_2)
                .setBigContentTitle(contentTitle)
                .setSummaryText(summaryText)
        )
```

- Inbox style:

```
 builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle(builder)
                .addLine(charsequence)
                .setBigContentTitle(contentTitle)
                .setSummaryText(summaryText)
        )
```

- DecoratedCustomViewStyle
- MessagingStyle

**2.** You can create a custom `layout.xml` for your notification:

```
RemoteViews layout = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_layout);
//you can use different methods to customize your layout programmatically:
layout.setTextViewText(viewId, text); //set text to TextView
layout.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageviewID_in_your_layout, your_bitmap); //set bitmap to ImageView
layout.addView(...)
...

//Finally assign RemoteViews to the NotificationCompat.Builder:
NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setContent(layout).(...).build();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, i'll check it out

Comment: @DennisVA Your welcome. be sure these methods work well!